# Organizational term meaning "order appearing in a book" as contrasted to chronological

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, adverbs

Is there a word that means "in the order something appears in a book or document" as opposed to chronological meaning "the order something occurs in time."

Ignoring the fact that my examples may not be the best literature, this is the type of usage that I am looking for.

Sample sentence as an adverb: The dialogue immediately preceding this event chronologically was....

My desired sentence: The dialogue immediately preceding this event *[the word I am looking for]*...

Sample sentence as an adjective: Chronological story telling has its place, but so does *[my word]* story telling.

Following are a few organizational terms that I can think of which are included here for benefit of the community. The word I am looking for belongs to this set.

Chronological, Geographical, Topical, ...

Comment: Perhaps "plot-line storytelling," or "scene by scene storytelling," or "chapter by chapter storytelling," or "thematic storytelling," or "linear storytelling," or "discursive storytelling," to give you just a few. Don

Answer (score 1):

**"sequential"**, or **"in sequence"**, comes to mind.

> - [**sequential**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sequential) - (adj) "of, relating to, or arranged in a particular order or sequence
>     : happening in a series or sequence."
> - **in sequence**, **sequentially** (adv)
>
> **"Chronological story telling has its place, but so does sequential story telling."**

**serial** may also fit.

> - [**serial**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serial) (adj) - arranged or happening in a series
> - **serially** (adv)

e.g.

- a serial port
- a serial printer
- a serial killer
- serial processing
- serial verbs
- serial interfaces